# 'all the following are' OR 'the following are all'

Tags: grammaticality, logic

Which of these is grammatically correct?

"The statement is incorrect when the following are all true:"
"The statement is incorrect when all the following are true:"

Comment: Both seem fine. Could explain why you feel one of them is not correct?

Comment: ***Why do you think that there has to be one right answer?*** That simply is not how language works.

Comment: Thanks - I just wanted to make sure if there was a right and a wrong way on this occasion as it is in a formal/legal document.  Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

In both examples, both 'all' and 'true' modify 'the following', so the sentences are functionally equivalent. I personally prefer the latter usage, but either one is more than acceptable.